# switching gender pronouns in strings and unums

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, replace, enums

I'm making a game that involves with the players choice of gender and want to reflect the dialogue of the player's choice with the correct pronouns. I was thinking of using boolean but was advice not to as it seems kind of bad making one of the genders to be true and the other to be false. So trying to use enums on this but my only problem is how to implement it correctly and have it working. Haven't really used enums that much before to be use for strings.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class UITextBoxScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text mytext;
    enum Gender
    {
        None, Male, Female
    }
    enum States
    {
        Instructions, Warning, YourGender, Test
    }

    Gender playerGender = Gender.None;

    Gender playersGender = Gender.Male;

    Gender playGender = Gender.Female;


    int gender = 0; // using 0 or 1  (or 0, 1, 2.. if you might ever have 'unset')
    string[] heshe = { "he", "she" };
    string[] hisher = { "his", "her" };
    string[] himher = { "him", "her" };
```

Then this is the target area of where it should hit and affect the user's choice:

```
    void state_YourGender()
    {
        mytext.text = "Okay!" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "What is your love interest gender?" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "A) Male" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "S) Female";

        timer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            myState = States.Test;
            gender = 0;
            Gender playersGender = Gender.Male;
        }

        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            myState = States.Test;

        }
    }

    void state_Test()
    {
        string phrase=" _heshe_was really happy";
        string newPhrase = phrase.Replace("_HESHE_", heshe[gender]);

        timer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer <= 0 && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            timer = timerVal;
            myState = States.YourGender;
        }
    }
```

I have been trying to experiment and find a way to call out the string to return to me but the string itself is not returning at all. I'm also using mytextbox and the area of a small box for the dialogue to show up and it has been working fine; no issues there. Any advice or tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using enums to store exclusive values like gender is a good idea, but there are a few design decisions in your code that are not good ideas. First, you already have four global variables just to store one player's gender roles. That's already too many, and will get worse with every player or NPC you add. Instead, create a class for storing people:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; private set; }
    public Gender LoveInterestGender { get; private set; }
    public Person(string name, Gender gender, Gender loveInterestGender)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

        Name = name;
        Gender = gender;
        LoveInterestGender = loveInterestGender;
    }
}
```

Beginners are strangely reluctant to create new classes. Don't be; that is the main way you will simplify your code. Now you can create your player through code or a UI:

```
var player = new Person(name: "Hiro Protagonist", gender: Gender.Male, loveInterestGender: Gender.Female);
```

It's also a bad idea to try to customize dialog using string replacement; often you want to change the actual dialog, not just replace every “he” with “she” or such. You need to specify rules for dialogs to follow. For example, we could specify a different rule for each dialog depending on the gender of the speaker and listener. How do you do that? With another class, of course. Though, for reasons I won't go into, in this particular case a readonly struct would be better:

```
public struct DialogSpecifier : IEquatable<DialogSpecifier>
{
    public readonly Gender SpeakerGender;
    public readonly Gender ListenerGender;

    public DialogSpecifier(Gender speakerGender, Gender listenerGender)
    {
        SpeakerGender = speakerGender;
        ListenerGender = listenerGender;
    }

    public bool Equals(DialogSpecifier other)
    {
        return SpeakerGender==other.SpeakerGender
            && ListenerGender==other.ListenerGender;
    }
}
```

Okay, so now we have people, and rules for dialogs. How do we make people speak to each other using these rules? We could write a bunch of code for each person for each rule for each gender. Wow, that's a lot of code! How do we simplify code again? Oh yeah, create a class:

```
public class Dialogue
{
    Dictionary<DialogSpecifier, string> specifiedDialog = new Dictionary<DialogSpecifier, string>();

    public Dialogue(string noneToNone)
    {
        specifiedDialog.Add(new DialogSpecifier(Gender.None, Gender.None), noneToNone);
    }

    public Dialogue Add(DialogSpecifier specifier, string dialogue)
    {
        specifiedDialog.Add(specifier, dialogue);
        return this;
    }

    public string OpeningGambit(Person speaker, Person listener)
    {
        string gambit;
        if (specifiedDialog.TryGetValue(new DialogSpecifier(speakerGender: speaker.Gender, listenerGender: listener.Gender),
                out gambit))
            return gambit;

        return specifiedDialog[new DialogSpecifier(Gender.None, Gender.None)];
    }
}
```

Okay, so now let's create some people and dialogues:

```
var introduction = new Dialogue("Hello")
    .Add(new DialogSpecifier(Gender.Male, Gender.Male), "Wassup?");
var npc = new Person(name: "Juanita Marquez", gender: Gender.Female, loveInterestGender: Gender.Male);

var gambit = introduction.OpeningGambit(player, npc);
```

Simple, right? That's because we created classes and didn't try to write code for every possible permutation. This is easily extensible, too; we can Add gambits for different situations, or change `specifiedDialog` to a `Dictionary<DialogSpecifier, List<string>>` so we can have a list of gambits instead of a single one for each specifier. We could add more rules to `DialogSpecifier`, for example to behave differently if the listener is the speaker's `LoveInterestGender`. Doing that only requires changing one class; you don't have to rewrite all your code every time you add something.